# How can fragmentation result in a higher mass than parent ion?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I've collected MS/MS data on a (highly modified) peptide. While most of the data is fine, I've noticed that I have some daughter ions which are *higher* in mass than the parent ion (in this case, an increase from 879 m/z to 895 m/z).

My initial guess was that perhaps the parent ion was actually doubly charged, but the isotope increment by 1 m/z - so this means it's definitely singly charged, right? So how could CID fragmentation result in a higher mass?

For context, this is a Bruker "HCT" instrument, which uses an ion trap, and the data was collected from a direct flow injection in negative-mode ESI using methanol with no additives.

I was under the impression that concentrations in gas-phase are far too low for inter-molecular chemistry; in this case, however, the 895 peak is taller than all the rest!

Comment: Than the compound in there has higher molecular mass.

Comment: @Mithoron, this is not the typical case. Adducts are more common in ESI-MS. These adduct peaks appear at a higher mass than the original compound. Mohger, is your compound highly purified or not? m/z of 895 in positive mode is a contaminant from surfactants but you mention negative ion mode.

Comment: A very good reference for contaminants in MS is Interferences and contaminants encountered in modern mass spectrometry, Bernd O. Keller et al. in Analytica Chimica Acta (2008).

Comment: @AChem my molecule is fairly purified, but it's a shared instrument and there could be someone else's contamination. The surfactant idea is interesting: maybe there's a multiply-charged contaminant ion that's isobaric with the parent ion? Thanks for the reference, their spreadsheet looks incredibly useful :)

Comment: @mohger, this is why blanks in analytical chemistry are *extremely* critical. You can easily eliminate cross contamination "theory" if you run a solvent blank.